# Send String to a function inside a class

Tags: lcd, string

I made a little class for handling menus. When creating a new instance, I pass a reference to the `oled` object made in `main.cpp`. Yet when I want to render a string using a variable, it throws an error. But I can pass a string directly to the render function with no problems. See comments in the code for what is working and what is not.

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "U8glib.h"
#pragma once

class Menu {
  U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64& oled;

  public:
    Menu(U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64& oled): oled(oled) {
      this->oled = oled;
    };
    void render() {
      this->oled.firstPage();
      do {
        String text = "test2";
        this->oled.setFont(u8g_font_unifont);
        this->oled.setPrintPos(0, 20);
        this->oled.drawStr(text); // not working
        this->oled.drawStr(text.c_str()); // not working
        this->oled.drawStr("works"); // works
      } while (this->oled.nextPage());
    }
  };
```

In the case of `this->oled.drawStr(text);` the error is:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to 'U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64::drawStr(String&)
```

In case of `this->oled.drawStr(text.c_str())` the error is:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to 'U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64::drawStr(const char*)
```

How I create the instance in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 oled(U8G_I2C_OPT_NONE);
Menu menu(oled);
menu.render();
```

Comment: I can find no mention of a `drawStr` function in the current U8glib library that takes only one parameter. What version are you using and where did you get it?

Comment: I udated to u8g2 lib, passed 3 parameters (int int c_str) and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @MartinVelinský if you updated it, then edit the question and ADD the new code, otherwise it is impossible to properly answer

Answer (score 2):

Try with the new version, U8g2lib.

With that version, you can write code like this:

```
String t1 = "Grow";
String t2 = "Room";
u8g2.firstPage();
do {
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_logisoso24_tf);
  u8g2.drawStr(32, 24, t1.c_str());
  u8g2.drawStr(32, 60, t2.c_str());
} while(u8g2.nextPage());
```

Comment: even with a u8g2 lib, I'm still getting the same compile error

Comment: Post a complete updated sketch with u8g2lib to better resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the String class.  It wastes memory on a system that is already constrained by memory.  Define your strings as const char * and you won't have any problems.

```
const char* t1 = "Grow";
const char* t2 = "Room";
u8g2.firstPage();
do {
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_logisoso24_tf);
  u8g2.drawStr(32, 24, t1);
  u8g2.drawStr(32, 60, t2);
} while(u8g2.nextPage());
```